# How to dynamically change checkbox when selecting different items in combobox

Tags: c#, user-interface, checkbox, combobox

I am trying to create a GUI where selecting an item inside the combobox changes whether each checkbox is checked or not.

The GUI has alot of checkboxes which user can check or uncheck.

For example, user can select "item 1" from combobox, which then user checks whatever checkbox he wants to check. Then, when the user selects "item 2", checkboxes which were checked from "item 1" will be greyed out and user can check or uncheck from the rest.

Each items from combobox basically saves user's choices on the checkbox.

Can anyone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example 4 checkboxes, 1 combobox

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            comboBox1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        comboBox1.Text = comboBox1.Items[0].ToString();
    }
    bool needtoupdate = true;
    public class CheckedItems
    {
        public CheckedItems()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
            {
                b[i] = false;
            }
        }
        public bool[] b = { false, false, false, false };
    }

    CheckedItems[] allcheckeditems = { new CheckedItems(), new CheckedItems(), new CheckedItems()};

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        needtoupdate = false;
        checkBox1.Checked = allcheckeditems[Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.Text)].b[0];
        checkBox2.Checked = allcheckeditems[Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.Text)].b[1];
        checkBox3.Checked = allcheckeditems[Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.Text)].b[2];
        checkBox4.Checked = allcheckeditems[Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.Text)].b[3];
        needtoupdate = true;
    }

    void saveallchecked()
    {
        if (!needtoupdate) return;
        allcheckeditems[Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.Text)].b[0] = checkBox1.Checked;
        allcheckeditems[Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.Text)].b[1] = checkBox2.Checked;
        allcheckeditems[Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.Text)].b[2] = checkBox3.Checked;
        allcheckeditems[Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.Text)].b[3] = checkBox4.Checked;
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveallchecked();
    }

    private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveallchecked();
    }

    private void checkBox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveallchecked();
    }

    private void checkBox4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveallchecked();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you this one has been a great help.

Answer (score 0):

I would put your checkboxes and the combo inside a update panel, create a event for when the user changes the combobox, in this event you have to loop to see which are checked and this ones you set enable false(they will appear gray).

Was it useful ?